# How do I change the hitbox of an image in CSS?

Tags: html, css, image, hyperlink

I made a website where in the beginning, you see an arrow pointing down, so you can click on it to scroll down automatically. I changed the position of the image with `padding-left and padding-top` to get it into the lower center.

The problem is that the clickable area of the image goes from the top left to the image.

How do I decrease the hitbox?

Thanks in advance

P.s.: I did the HTML like this:

```
<a href="...">
  <img src="..."></img>
</a>
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow, please add your code to make it easier for others to answer. Have a look at [ask] for more information.

Comment: Just a guess not being able to check the code, but you could try `position: fixed; bottom: 10px;` or something similar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use margin instead of padding if your layout will tolerate it. Otherwise use `box-sizing: border-box`.

[Here](https://blog.hubspot.com/website/css-margin-vs-padding#:%7E:text=What%27s%20the%20Difference%20Between%20Margin,and%20the%20content%20inside%20it.&text=In%20creating%20the%20gap%2C%20the,the%20border%20of%20an%20element.) is a good, short read regarding that.